# FLUTTER TrackingScrollController is not syncing at all

Tags: scroll, dart, controller, flutter, synchronization

i tried using `SingleChildScrollView` with a single `TrackingScrollController`.

my code is already very similar as of [this documentation here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TrackingScrollController-class.html)

but the scrolls are still not scrolling together at all.

i also tried using multiple `controller` and use `jumpTo` to set the offsets.
but i gives me a stack overflow errors.

---

so my question is:
**how do i properly implement the `TrackingScrollController` in a working code?**

please ***provide me a working main.dart in the answers*** so i can run it and see if it works.
i am always seeing snipets of codes here and there and have no idea where to put what where.

Thank you very much.